# wordpress double quotes are converting to inverted commas thats why design is breaking

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-popover, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am wring a wordpress plugin where I have to show some data in bootstrap popover
for that I am populating some information in data attributes

it is working on my local server, also it is working on live server if I am rendering my content inside an iframe.

but when I am rendering my HTML inside wordpress content then it is breaking down.
below is my code

```
<?php $iTag = " <i class='float-end btn-popover btn-close'></i>"; ?>
<i class="fa fa-info-circle ms-3 popover-handler no-collapsable" 
         data-bs-title="<?php echo str_replace('"',"'",$item['title']) . $iTag; ?>"
         data-html="true" data-bs-content="<?php echo str_replace('"',"'", stripslashes($item['meta_info'])); ?>"></i>
```

And below is the output

[image]

if you notice `data-bs-title` value is started with double quotes but ended with inverted commas, actually it is considering `data-bs-title` value untill next double qoutes which I mard with green.

while debugging I did many things like
I tried removig `class` attribute from i tag but still it was not fixed
I also tried removing whole i tag than it worked, so it means there is something with `<>` signs?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has `wptexturize()`, which according to their documentation "replaces common plain text characters with formatted entities." (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wptexturize/).

This is what is happening in your case. Please look at the "[more information](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wptexturize/#more-information)" section in the above linked documentation page on how to "get rid" of it.

The most at hand solution would be

```
add_filter('run_wptexturize', false);
```

but you might not want to fully deactivate it.

You might want to use shortcodes (their content is not wptexturized) or `<script>` tags instead.